# Android LuckyWheel Library add onClick method on Canvas item

Tags: android

I am using [this](https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel) library to draw a circle with eight equal triangular parts and rotate them. Now I want to add an `OnClick` feature, so when user clicks on one of the triangles it will rotate to the selected position. This library already has code for rotating an item by it's index, but I cannot figure out how to find the index of the triangle which has been clicked. Has anyone worked with this before? Any help is appreciated.

Code:

**LuckyWheelView.java**

```
public class LuckyWheelView extends RelativeLayout implements PielView.PieRotateListener {
private int mBackgroundColor;
private int mTextColor;
private int mTopTextSize;
private int mSecondaryTextSize;
private int mBorderColor;
private int mTopTextPadding;
private int mEdgeWidth;
private Drawable mCenterImage;
private Drawable mCursorImage;

private PielView pielView;
private ImageView ivCursorView;

private LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener mLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener;

@Override
public void rotateDone(int index) {
    if (mLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener != null) {
        mLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener.LuckyRoundItemSelected(index);
    }
}

public interface LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener {
    void LuckyRoundItemSelected(int index);
}

public void setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener listener) {
    this.mLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener = listener;
}

public LuckyWheelView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public LuckyWheelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * @param ctx
 * @param attrs
 */
private void init(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray typedArray = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LuckyWheelView);
        mBackgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwBackgroundColor, 0xffcc0000);
        mTopTextSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwTopTextSize, (int) LuckyWheelUtils.convertDpToPixel(10f, getContext()));
        mSecondaryTextSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwSecondaryTextSize, (int) LuckyWheelUtils.convertDpToPixel(20f, getContext()));
        mTextColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwTopTextColor, 0);
        mTopTextPadding = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwTopTextPadding, (int) LuckyWheelUtils.convertDpToPixel(10f, getContext())) + (int) LuckyWheelUtils.convertDpToPixel(10f, getContext());
        mCursorImage = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwCursor);
        mCenterImage = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwCenterImage);
        mEdgeWidth = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwEdgeWidth, 10);
        mBorderColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.LuckyWheelView_lkwEdgeColor, 0);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lucky_wheel_layout, this, false);

    pielView = frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.pieView);
    ivCursorView = frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.cursorView);

    pielView.setPieRotateListener(this);
    pielView.setPieBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor);
    pielView.setTopTextPadding(mTopTextPadding);
    pielView.setTopTextSize(mTopTextSize);
    pielView.setSecondaryTextSizeSize(mSecondaryTextSize);
    pielView.setPieCenterImage(mCenterImage);
    pielView.setBorderColor(mBorderColor);
    pielView.setBorderWidth(mEdgeWidth);


    if (mTextColor != 0)
        pielView.setPieTextColor(mTextColor);

    ivCursorView.setImageDrawable(mCursorImage);

    addView(frameLayout);

}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //This is to control that the touch events triggered are only going to the PieView
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (isPielView(getChildAt(i))) {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isPielView(View view) {
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (isPielView(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return view instanceof PielView;
}

public void setLuckyWheelBackgrouldColor(int color) {
    pielView.setPieBackgroundColor(color);
}

public void setLuckyWheelCursorImage(int drawable) {
    ivCursorView.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
}

public void setLuckyWheelCenterImage(Drawable drawable) {
    pielView.setPieCenterImage(drawable);
}

public void setBorderColor(int color) {
    pielView.setBorderColor(color);
}

public void setLuckyWheelTextColor(int color) {
    pielView.setPieTextColor(color);
}

/**
 * @param data
 */
public void setData(List<LuckyItem> data) {
    pielView.setData(data);
}

/**
 * @param numberOfRound
 */
public void setRound(int numberOfRound) {
    pielView.setRound(numberOfRound);
}

/**
 * @param fixedNumber
 */
public void setPredeterminedNumber(int fixedNumber) {
    pielView.setPredeterminedNumber(fixedNumber);
}

public void startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(int index) {
    pielView.rotateTo(index);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    List<LuckyItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
    LuckyWheelView luckyWheelView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    luckyWheelView = (LuckyWheelView) findViewById(R.id.luckyWheel);

    LuckyItem luckyItem1 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem1.topText = "100";
    luckyItem1.icon = R.drawable.test1;*/
    luckyItem1.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
    data.add(luckyItem1);

    LuckyItem luckyItem2 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem2.topText = "200";
    luckyItem2.icon = R.drawable.test2;*/
    luckyItem2.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
    data.add(luckyItem2);

    LuckyItem luckyItem3 = new LuckyItem();
    /*uckyItem3.topText = "300";
    luckyItem3.icon = R.drawable.test3;*/
    luckyItem3.color = 0xffFFCC80;
    data.add(luckyItem3);

    //////////////////
    final LuckyItem luckyItem4 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem4.topText = "400";
    luckyItem4.icon = R.drawable.test4;*/
    luckyItem4.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
    data.add(luckyItem4);

    LuckyItem luckyItem5 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem5.topText = "500";
    luckyItem5.icon = R.drawable.test5;*/
    luckyItem5.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
    data.add(luckyItem5);

    LuckyItem luckyItem6 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem6.topText = "600";
    luckyItem6.icon = R.drawable.test6;*/
    luckyItem6.color = 0xffFFCC80;
    data.add(luckyItem6);
    //////////////////

    //////////////////////
    LuckyItem luckyItem7 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem7.topText = "700";
    luckyItem7.icon = R.drawable.test7;*/
    luckyItem7.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
    data.add(luckyItem7);

    LuckyItem luckyItem8 = new LuckyItem();
    /*luckyItem8.topText = "800";
    luckyItem8.icon = R.drawable.test8;*/
    luckyItem8.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
    data.add(luckyItem8);

    /////////////////////

    luckyWheelView.setData(data);
    luckyWheelView.setRound(0);


    luckyWheelView.setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(new LuckyWheelView.LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void LuckyRoundItemSelected(int index) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).topText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Have you find any solution?